# How can I place text inside an SVG circle with React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
import React from 'react';

var SVGComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <svg {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</svg>;
    }
});

var Circle = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <circle {...this.props}>{this.props.children}</circle>;
    }
});

var MakeCircles = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return(
            <div>
                <SVGComponent height="110" width="500">
                    <Circle 
                        cx="50" cy="55" r="45"
                        fill="none"
                        stroke="#F0CE01" strokeWidth="4" />     
                </SVGComponent>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
export default MakeCircles
```

I'm trying to get some text inside the circle but finding it absolutely difficult. Is there something/some add-on that can help me with this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "trying to get some text inside the circle" ? Where is this text in your example ?

Comment: Sorry I took it out of the code because it didn't work. I've tried putting it outside of the SVGComponent tags, but it seems like I'd need to rely on positioning to get it to the right spot. I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution out there that may involve the SVGComponent or Circle classes I created.

Comment: Do you want the circle to be a set size, or adjust to the size of the text?

Comment: I recommend getting rid of SVGComponent and Circle components. Using <svg> or <circle> instead, you'll have the same result. Unless you already know which extra properties or behaviors those components will address, I think they'll make your codebase (or sample) larger and complex, and never serve a purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A circle is a layer, and so is a Text node. You have to have them as separate layers and make them look as if they belong together:

```
<SVGComponent height="110" width="500">
    <Circle cx="50" cy="55" r="45" fill="none" stroke="#F0CE01" strokeWidth="4" />
    <text textAnchor="middle" x="250" y="55">Circle Text</text>
</SVGComponent>
```

Comment: Tiny thing: `text-anchor` should be `textAnchor` in React.

Comment: this didn't work for me.. only the text renders 
`<div height="110" width="500">`
`<circle cx="50" cy="55" r="45" fill="none" stroke="#F0CE01" strokeWidth="4" />`
`<text textAnchor="middle" x="250" y="55"> Circle Text</text>`
`</div>`